# IntelliJ key combo works by default on Mac OS, how can I access on Windows?

Tags: windows, keyboard-shortcuts, intellij-idea

I use IntelliJ IDEA, on Mac OS at work, and on Windows 10 at home. On Mac OS, if I hold <kbd>⌘</kbd> and press a left/right arrow key, the cursor jumps to the left/right end of the current line, excluding whitespace. Similar to how <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + arrows snap the cursor past the current syntax token. However, I can't find this functionality on Windows; <kbd>⊞ Win</kbd> + left/right instead snaps the IntelliJ window to edges of the screen.

Can this behavior be accessed on Windows?

Comment: Try <ctrl><alt><arrow>

Comment: @DavidPostill that has the same effect as just alt + arrow.

Answer (score 0):

I found the ability to rebind the key combos in

- Settings
- Keymap
- Editor Actions
- Move Caret to Line (End|Start) (with Selection)?